# How to turn off certificate revocation for a WCF service's client?

Tags: wcf, soaphttpclientprotocol, certificate-revocation

How can I turn off certificate revocation for a WCF service's client?
The client proxy was generated by wsdl.exe and inherits SoapHttpClientProtocol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx

Which takes a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` Delegate:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx

I've never dealt with a revoked certificate before (I have hand to handle other issues such as expired SSL's), but I'm guessing you'd just do something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);

        // Do WCF calls...
    }

    public static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, 
                              X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if(sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
        {
            foreach(X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if(chainStatus.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.Revoked)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        /* 
         WARNING!
     
         You should perform other cert validation checks here and not blindly 
         override your cert validation by returning true.

         Otherwise the secure channel between your client and service
         may not be secure.

        */

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set certificate validation and revocation options in the config file for your application:

http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,e9bb929b-d0b4-4626-b302-1d2715fc344a.aspx

Comment: This is only true for client certificates authentication on the server. For server certificate authentication on the client you must use the above method.

Comment: Please do not post answers that are just links. There are two main reasons for this: it's usually much more helpful to answer users' specific issues directly, and even links to good resources sometimes go bad. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for more detail.